# XPath increment with Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, increment

I'm trying to increment the variable 'xpath', but it does not work with the code underneath. Does anyone know how I can fix this? If I don't use the function, the inner loop does not work, so I need to keep that part that way (as far as I know).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
#Function to export data
def loop_function():

    #Search client
    searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
    searchCustomerButton.click()    

    #Loop client ID's
    followLoop = range(0, 10)
    for x in followLoop:
        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__'
        xpath += str(x)
        xpath += '"]/td[3]'
        
        #Click on cliënt ID
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        #Click on Zorgtraject
        zorgtrajectButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
        zorgtrajectButton.click()

        #Loop Zorgtraject ID's
        followLoop2 = range(0,10)
        for x in followLoop2:
            try:
                xpath2 = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid1_ctl00__'
                xpath2 += str(x)
                xpath2 += '"]/td[2]'

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()

                #Dossier button
                dossierButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span')
                dossierButton.click()

                #Dropdown select
                dropdownSelector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
                dropdownSelector.click()

                #Prevent not interactable error
                time.sleep(2)

                #Select 50
                selectDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[4]')
                selectDropdown.click()

                #Check all documents
                tickDossier = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_headerChkboxPrint"]')
                tickDossier.click()

                #Click print
                printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]')
                printButton.click()

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                zorgtrajectButton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
                zorgtrajectButton2.click()

            #If no Zorgtraject ID, start function over
            except NoSuchElementException:
                loop_function()
                
exec(loop_function())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using f-string?

```
xpath = f'//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__{x}"]/td[3]'
```

But, if this pattern is always true, I would prefer using `starts-with` to find all elements at once, and then loop.

```
xpath = '//*[starts-with(@id, "ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__")]'
```

I guess you could accomplish what you want looping through elements and breaking the second loop when NoSuchElementException:

```
# Function to export data
def loop_function():
    # Search client
    searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
    searchCustomerButton.click()

    # Loop client ID's
    followLoop = range(0, 10)
    for x in followLoop:
        xpath = f'//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__{x}"]/td[3]'

        # Click on cliënt ID
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        # Click on Zorgtraject
        zorgtrajectButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
        zorgtrajectButton.click()

        # Loop Zorgtraject ID's
        followLoop2 = range(0, 10)
        for x in followLoop2:
            try:
                xpath2 = f'//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid1_ctl00__{x}"]/td[2]'

                # Click on Zorgtraject ID
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()

                # Dossier button
                dossierButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span')
                dossierButton.click()

                # Dropdown select
                dropdownSelector = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
                dropdownSelector.click()

                # Prevent not interactable error
                time.sleep(2)

                # Select 50
                selectDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[4]')
                selectDropdown.click()

                # Check all documents
                tickDossier = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_headerChkboxPrint"]')
                tickDossier.click()

                # Click print
                printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]')
                printButton.click()

                # Click on Zorgtraject ID
                zorgtrajectButton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
                zorgtrajectButton2.click()

            # If no Zorgtraject ID, break the inner loop 
            # and continue the outer loop iteration
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Comment: Hi @montovaneli, I'm trying to increment 'xpath', not 'xpath2' (xpath2 increments fine). When the exception occurs, I call the function again. I think that's why I does not increment. Do you know how to resolve this? 

For the code to work correctly, I have to call the function again when an exception occurs.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, when `NoSuchElementException` occurs in the second loop, you want to stop this iteration and continue iterating from the beginning of the first loop. That's why I replaced `loop_function()` by `break` into the exception handling.